# Adding features to plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm struggling doing the following thing:

I did a simulation of a Stock Price, and saved the numbers in a matrix (each simulation is by columns, in row there are time instants).

Here is the first part of the code that I used to set the parameters to simulate, I will save the trajectories in a matrix STORE_SIM

```css
r=0.05 %parameters
mu = r; sigma = 0.5; S0 = 12;
T = 1;
TIME = 10;
Dt = 1/TIME;
SIM=50
BARR=8
STORE_SIM=zeros(TIME+1,SIM);
```

I added an extra row to insert the starting value of the stock price S0=12 for plotting from the starting point.

Now what I had done here is:
**if in these vectors(columns)  there is at least one one value of the vector that goes below the threshold, then save in a matrix called STORE_SIM_1** (there could be more times that the price passes the threshold, but it's sufficient that was passed once.

On the other hand, **if in one of these vectors(columns), there are no values that go below the threshold, then save in a matrix called NOTACTIVE**

```css
for i=1:SIM
DW = sqrt(Dt)*randn(1,TIME);
W = cumsum(DW);

Strue = S0*exp((mu-0.5*sigma^2)*([Dt:Dt:T])+sigma*W);

STORE_SIM(1,i)=S0
STORE_SIM(2:TIME+1,i)=Strue


idx = STORE_SIM>BARR;
to_del=all(idx,1);
STORE_SIM_1=STORE_SIM;
STORE_SIM_1(:,to_del)=0;


index = STORE_SIM<BARR
logic=any(index)
NOTACTIVE=STORE_SIM
NOTACTIVE(:,logic)=0
end
```

Now that I had done these two matrices, I plotted in the following way:

```css
figure(1)
hold on
xlim([1 12])
for i=1:SIM
plot(NOTACTIVE(:,i),'--')
end
hold on
for i=1:SIM
    plot(STORE_SIM_1(:,i),'k')
end
hold on
plot([1,12],[8,8],'r','LineWidth',3)
```

Now what I'd like to do is to add to this plot some red lines representing each one **the first time that a value in the vector(column) went beyond the threshold**.

1. I don't know how to set a matrix in which I can save the row number which correspond to the first time the threshold was passed,
2. I don't know how to add these feature to my plot in way that looks like to my picture.

[image: Simulated Trajectories]

BTW. If you have suggestion on the code in general, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are a lot of improvements that can be applied to your code... but instead of adjusting it step by step, I decided to change it completely vectorizing the whole process. Hence, I think it's kinda pointless to list 'em all since they are no more... but I'll focus on what remains:

- Try to save up as much memory as possible and to perform as less iterations as possible. Instead of zero filling the wrong columns in your simulations matrix and filling an equally sized, zero-filled matrix with those... just split the two matrices.
- On a cosmetic point of view, I think it's better to print the wrong simulations first (with a very soft color) and then the good ones, letting the latter override the former. This will help highlighting the good simulations, which should be much more important.
- Try to parametrize every function you call with the initial variables you define. This will make easier to change one or more parameters without being forced to redesign code logics.

Here is the final code:

```
% Define the simulation parameters...
mu = 0.05;
sigma = 0.5;
s0 = 12;
n = 50;
thr = 8;

% Define the time parameters...
tn = 1;
t = 10;
dt = 1 / t;
tl = t + 1;

% Perform the simulation...
s0_all = repmat(s0,1,n);
t_all = repmat((dt:dt:tn).',1,n);
sim = [s0_all; repmat(s0_all,t,1) .* exp(((mu - 0.5 * sigma^2) .* t_all) + (sigma .* cumsum(sqrt(dt) .* randn(t,n))))];

% Split the simulations into two groups based on the threshold...
idx = any(sim < thr,1);
bad = sim(:,idx);
sim(:,idx) = [];

% Find the spots where the thresholds are violated...
[bad_rows,bad_cols] = find(bad < thr);
[~,bad_rows_uni_idx] = unique(bad_cols,'first');
bad_x = unique(bad_rows(bad_rows_uni_idx));

% Plot the figure...
figure();
xlim([1 tl]);

hold on;

for ii = 1:size(bad,2)
    plot(bad(:,ii),'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5],'LineStyle','--');
end

for ii = 1:size(sim,2)
    plot(sim(:,ii));
end

for ii = 1:numel(bad_x)
    line(repelem(bad_x(ii),2),[0 thr],'Color','r','LineWidth',3);
end

line([1 tl],[thr thr],'Color','r','LineWidth',3);

hold off;
```

And this is the final output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you @Tommaso Beluzzo. I switched your color choose, because i was aiming for the trajectories that went down the barrier, the ones the never went down should be neglected. I was studying your code i have 2 question.. when you % Split the simulations into two groups based on the threshold... idx = any(sim < thr,1); how do you make the code working for columns? for example if i wanted to do the same thing but in a row sight? Another thing i can't figure out is what is the logic of the command unique with 'first' that you used. Anyway thank you so much

Comment: Unique with first is used to obtain the first index of the duplicate occurrences. For a column-wise any use 2 instead of 1 as the second parameter.